# Estimation/identification simple problem

Tags: modeling

I have this model in my mind:
$ y_t = c + \phi x_{t-1}^k + \eta_t$ where $\eta_t$ is N.I.D.

In your opinion is possible to estimate $k$?

Comment: What is N.I.D.?  Normal and identically distributed or normal and independent and identically distributed or something else??

Comment: Is there some special significance of having $x_{t-1}$ instead of $x_t$?

Comment: @Chernick normal and independent and identically distributed

Comment: @mpiktas just to allow forecasts

Comment: I gave the answer before your last 2 comments. It still holds.

Comment: @Marco using "@Chernick" does not alert me to your comment.  You need to use "@Michael" or "@MichaelChernick".  I found your comment because i looked up this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well simple simulation example says so:

```
> set.seed(13)
> x<-runif(100,1,2)
> y<-1+2*x^3+rnorm(100)
> nls(y~a+b*x^k,start=list(a=0,b=1,k=2))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y ~ a + b * x^k 
   data:  parent.frame() 
    a     b     k 
0.921 2.155 2.846 
 residual sum-of-squares: 83.94

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.285e-08
```

And here is the graphical comparison

```
> plot(x,y)
> dt<-data.frame(x,fit=predict(nl))
> dt<-dt[order(dt$x),]
> lines(dt$x,dt$fit,col="red")
> lines(dt$x,1+2*dt$x^3,col="black")
```

[image]

The black line is the theoretical line, the red one is the fit.

In this simple example it was easy to recover the coefficients. As always with real data there might be some caveats.

Comment: Mpiktas, thank you. So nonlinear regression model should be the way.

Comment: Do you think I can impose a restriction on k? For example k>0

Comment: Yes, you can using simple reparametrisation $k=\exp(m)$, and then fit the model $c+\phi x^{\exp(m)}$. But I suggest to think through why this restriction is necessary, since $k=0$ for example implies that there is no dependence on $x_t$.

Comment: I don't see why this is being called "nonlinear regression." It is a time series model. The power k for X$_t$$_-$$_1$ could be like a Box-Cox transformation in a linear model with the power being a parameter that can be estimated by maximum likelihood.  With k as a parameter it is nonlinear in the parameter k.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, well maximum likelihood estimate for $k$ in this stated model is non-linear least squares estimate. If you transform $y$ then you also transform $\eta$, which may not be a good thing. Why the objection to label of nonlinear regression? It has some bad properties?

Comment: I guess I think that a time series model should not be called regression.  Honestly as I wrote the answer I was thinking of the model being linear in the parameters as Box-Cox is a transformation applied to a linear model in the parameters. But when the parameter is itself estimated as part of the modeling it is truly a nonlinear estimation.  So I toned down my comment but decided not to drop it.  I understand yout point though @mpiktas.